# Nsight CUDA linkage problem between multiple .cu, .h and .c files

Tags: c++, c, cuda, nsight

This is the first time I am trying to build my CUDA app in NSight Ubuntu to benefit from optimization and profiling. This app works fine from terminal using `nvcc` (makefile) in Ubuntu 20 (or 18 ,16). I have multiple .cu, .c and .h files. All the files are first included in a flags.h file. My code starts with main.cu (has a `main()` function) file and this file has # include "flags.h" to make sure all the files are included to compile the code.
flags.h has a lot of `#define` as well to be later used in different .cu and .c files.

However, inside NSight, none of the #define parameters defined in flags.h are recognized  in any of the files and I am getting error.
Following is screenshot of error .
I am attaching a simple square_array problem split in 3 files (main.cu, flags.h  and square_.cu).

I can not build this in NSight. Can someone try to build it and let me know please.
Any help or suggestion will be much appreciated.

main.cu

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "flags.h"


int main(void) {

    int i;
    int *a_h, *a_d;

    CUDA_CHECK_RETURN(cudaMalloc((void**) &a_d, sizeof(int) * WORK_SIZE));
    a_h = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * WORK_SIZE);        // Allocate array on host

    for (i = 0; i < WORK_SIZE; i++)
        a_h[i] = i+2.;

    int block_size = 4;
    int n_blocks = WORK_SIZE/block_size + (WORK_SIZE%block_size == 0 ? 0:1);

    sq_array<<<n_blocks, block_size>>>(a_d);

    CUDA_CHECK_RETURN(cudaGetLastError());
    CUDA_CHECK_RETURN(cudaMemcpy(a_h, a_d, sizeof(int) * WORK_SIZE, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    for (i = 0; i < WORK_SIZE; i++)
        printf("Input value: %d \n", a_h[i]  );

    CUDA_CHECK_RETURN(cudaFree((void*) a_d));
    CUDA_CHECK_RETURN(cudaDeviceReset());

    return 0;
}
```

flags.h

```
#ifndef FLAGS_H_
#define FLAGS_H_

#include "square_.cu"
#define CUDA_CHECK_RETURN(value) {                                          \
    cudaError_t _m_cudaStat = value;                                        \
    if (_m_cudaStat != cudaSuccess) {                                       \
        fprintf(stderr, "Error %s at line %d in file %s\n",                 \
                cudaGetErrorString(_m_cudaStat), __LINE__, __FILE__);       \
        exit(1);                                                            \
    } }


#define WORK_SIZE 29

#endif /* FLAGS_H_ */
```

square_.cu

```
__global__ void sq_array( int *a) {
    int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    if (idx< WORK_SIZE) a[idx] = a[idx] * a[idx];

}
```

[image]

Comment: You are `#include`ing the `.cu` file *and* compiling the `.cu` file which means you would have two definitions of `sq_array`. When it is compiled stand alone, the header file defining `WORK_SIZE` is not specified. Do *not* include `.cu` or `.c` files -- compile separately and link.You need to arrange things so that `sq_array` and kernel call are in the same file which is compiled once.

Comment: @wcochran I am hoping that this should be a one-click build process because it works in terminal with a one line make command. This is a short code to explain my problem, but my real code is long and complicated with dozens of kernels therefore I can not put kernel call and kernel definition in the same file as you suggested. Also, when I have dozens of files, it will be quite tedious to compile and link separately. some youtube video will be helpful.

Comment: It works on the command line because you don't explicitly compile the `.cu` file, but the IDE will. You have to organize things differently. I work on massive code bases that use CUDA and our usual strategy is to create "host wrapper" functions that encapsulate the CUDA kernel code and invocation. Using `#include "square_.cu"` is just a bad idea -(you wouldn't do this with a `.c` file) -- every piece of separately compiled code that includes `flags.h` is going to define yet another version of the `sq_array` function.

Comment: can you post a solution without putting all code in one file? I posted this simple problem here to understand how to "build" a large code (split across multiple files) in Nsight IDE.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the your IDE is compiling `square_.cu` and compiling `main.cu` which is *also* compiling `square_.cu` again due to the `#include "square_.cu"` in `flags.h` which gives you two definitions of `sq_array`. When `square_.cu` is compiled the `WORK_SIZE` macro is not defined giving you a compile time error. When you compiled on the command line you did not compile `square_.cu` so you avoided this error.

In any case, it is a bad idea to `#include` `.cu` (or `.c` files). These should be compiled separately and then linked together.

You have to organize things differently.
I don't know the details of your code, but you can do something like this:

`square.cu`:

```
#include "square.h"
  
__global__ void sq_array( int *a) {
    int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    if (idx< WORK_SIZE) a[idx] = a[idx] * a[idx];

}
   
void host_sq_array(int *a_d) {
   int block_size = 4;
   int n_blocks = WORK_SIZE/block_size + (WORK_SIZE%block_size == 0 ? 0:1);   
   sq_array<<<n_blocks, block_size>>>(a_d);
}
```

`square.h`:

```
#ifndef SQUARE_H
#define SQUARE_H

#include "flags.h"  // REMOVE #include of .cu file!!!
void host_sq_array(int *a_d);

#endif
```

You can safely `#include square.h` which only includes constant, type definitions, and function prototypes.